# How to connect two databases in django for local and remote servers?

Tags: django

guys. I have a database, which I deployed on Heroku.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'd7mj3h2mco40v9',
    'USER': 'fwla1qyxgxrrqk',
    'PASSWORD': get_secret('DB_PASSWORD'), 
    'HOST': 'ec2-54-174-73-136.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

The problem is when I add comments objects on a local machine, they automatically downloaded to the remote database. It's not convenient.
I want to create, for example, a local database which will save all migrations or changes of my models, but not downloaded into a remote server. And when I need to download the data, I will do something and the changes are to appear on a remote database.
What do I need to do for this? How to make the right migrations and then work with them?
I'm newbie, please don't advice complicated things I can't understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really a newbie topic but you could look into db routers https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/multi-db/
Simplier would be the solution detailed here https://zerotobyte.com/django-multiple-databases-setup/ as you can see you just have to add db in the settings then make migrations by specifying the chosen db.Good luck